# Using useEffect fetch data several times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm just new to React Hooks, and playaround with it.

Just wondering if there any solutions that I could use useEffect to fetch data several times after componentDidMount.

Normally we use useEffect to fetch data based on some props change by passing them.

```
useEffect(()=> {
fetchApisomefunction()=>{}
},
[]); // normally do this for componentDidMount
```

How can I fetch data again after that?

---

UPDATE

callback function could solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are not using `Redux` or `Context API`,

so component A and B are not communicating to each other directly.

On the other hand, there will be a parent component which joins those two components.

As you've said, component B will post the data, and that should change parent's `state`.

Since react child component is being re-rendered whenever its parent component's `state` or `props` change, component A will also be re-rendered.

So all you have to do is to use `useEffect` without second parameter `[]`.

Actually it is not the question of using `Hooks`, but the question of react component structure.

Keep in mind that the two child components should not directly communicate to each other.